# Using RE with grep and sed for finding and replacing string in bash shell

Tags: xml, string, bash, sed, grep

I have hundreds of xml files containing the following string:

```
<METADATAEXTENSION COMPONENTVERSION ="8006001" DATATYPE ="STRING" DESCRIPTION ="Name of the Salesforce.com object" DOMAINNAME ="Salesforce" ISCLIENTEDITABLE ="NO" ISCLIENTVISIBLE ="YES" ISREUSABLE ="YES" ISSHAREREAD ="NO" ISSHAREWRITE ="NO" MAXLENGTH ="255" NAME ="Object Type" VALUE ="MY_STRING_TO_FIND__TheRestOfTheString__c" VENDORNAME ="INFORMATICA"/>
```

I need to find above string, find

```
MY_STRING_TO_FIND
```

sub-string and replace it with different value, e.g

```
MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE
```

so the end result should be this:

```
<METADATAEXTENSION COMPONENTVERSION ="8006001" DATATYPE ="STRING" DESCRIPTION ="Name of the Salesforce.com object" DOMAINNAME ="Salesforce" ISCLIENTEDITABLE ="NO" ISCLIENTVISIBLE ="YES" ISREUSABLE ="YES" ISSHAREREAD ="NO" ISSHAREWRITE ="NO" MAXLENGTH ="255" NAME ="Object Type" VALUE ="MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE__TheRestOfTheString__c" VENDORNAME ="INFORMATICA"/>
```

I created two variables:

```
MY_STRING_TO_FIND=AAA
MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE=BBB
```

and using the following command to find all files containing the entire string I need to find and then replace tokens accordingly:

```
grep -l "<METADATAEXTENSION[\s]*[$MY_STRING_TO_FIND]*" my_dir_with_xml_files | xargs sed -i "s/\A<METADATAEXTENSION[\s=\"._/>a-zA-Z0-9]+VALUE[\s=\"]+$MY_STRING_TO_FIND[__a-zA-Z\"\s=/>]+/\A<METADATAEXTENSION[\s=\"._/>a-zA-Z0-9]+VALUE[\s=\"]+$MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE[__a-zA-Z\"\s=/>]+/g"
```

but it does not work.

One complication is that string $MY_STRING_TO_FIND occurs in other parts of every xml file which I must not touch. So I need to find that particular string within sed expression and do a replacement only within this string.

I tried other various combinations to no avail...

I know that double quotes ignores RE but allows for parameter expansion and single quote treats everything literally so I cannot expand my parameters. So I am a bit lost here as to how to handle my case.

Essentially I am trying to solve a problem of dynamically handling Salesforce namespace name in Informatica.

I appreciate if you point me in the right direction

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should not try to manipulate XML with line-oriented tools. Use something like `xmlstarlet` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try bash script invoking sed like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_STRING_TO_FIND=${1:-AAA}
MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE=${2:-BBB}
TARGETS=${3:-*.xml}

sed -r "/<METADATAEXTENSION[^>]*${MY_STRING_TO_FIND}[^>]*>/ s/${MY_STRING_TO_FIND}/${MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE}/" ${TARGETS}
```

You can pass your strings as $1,$2 and the file pattern as $3.

If the script works for some test data, then you want to use either GNU seds `-i` inplace option or some output redirection to store the modified xml data instead of dumping it to the console.

Here the `s` substition is applied only to line matching the condition, i.e. your xml files need METADATAEXTENSION from `<` to `/>` in one line as given in the example. And other tags need to be on other separated lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the part you want :

```
sed -i "s/^\(<METADATAEXTENSION.*\)${MY_STRING_TO_FIND/\1${MY_STRING_TO_REPLACE}/" inputfiles
```